# ESP32 NVS get stored value fails with ESP_ERR_NVS_NOT_FOUND (0x1102)

Tags: arduino, esp32, persistent-storage, esp-idf

**Board: ESP32-WROOM with 16MB Flash size**

As the title: reading values written into ESP32 board NVS partition fail with error code 4354 (0x1102) which corresponds to ESP_ERR_NVS_NOT_FOUND.

The error on official ESP API page:
**ESP_ERR_NVS_NOT_FOUND = Id namespace doesn’t exist yet and mode is NVS_READONLY**

I cannot understand why, since I init with proper namespace and with **NVS_READWRITE** flag.

The code:

```
esp_err_t ret = 0;
nvs_handle handler = 0;
ret = nvs_flash_init_partition("nvs");
log_e("nvs_flash_init_partition CODE: %d", ret);

delay(500);

ret = nvs_open_from_partition("nvs", "tele", NVS_READWRITE, &handler);
log_e("nvs_open CODE: %d", ret);

delay(500);

ret = nvs_set_u8(handler, "kk", 7);
log_e("nvs_set_u8 CODE: %d", ret);

delay(500);

ret = nvs_commit(handler);
log_e("nvs_commit CODE: %d", ret);

delay(500);


int8_t max_buffer_size = 256; 
ret = nvs_get_i8(handler, "kk", &max_buffer_size);
log_e("nvs_get_u8 CODE: %d", ret);
log_e("nvs_get_u8 STORED: %d", max_buffer_size);

delay(500);

ret = nvs_flash_deinit_partition("nvs");
log_e("nvs_flash_deinit_partition CODE: %d", ret);

nvs_close(handler);
```

Note: I also tried without delays: same result.

the output:

```
begin(): nvs_flash_init_partition CODE: 0
begin(): nvs_open CODE: 0
begin(): nvs_set_u8 CODE: 0
begin(): nvs_commit CODE: 0
begin(): nvs_get_u8 CODE: 4354
begin(): nvs_get_u8 STORED: 0
begin(): nvs_flash_deinit_partition CODE: 0
```

Partitions:

```
 # Espressif ESP32 Partition Table
# Name, Type, SubType, Offset, Size, Flags

nvs,data,nvs,0x9000,16K,
otadata,data,ota,0xd000,8K,
phy_init,data,phy,0xf000,4K,
factory,app,factory,0x10000,8M,
ota_0,app,ota_0,0x810000,1M,
ota_1,app,ota_1,0x910000,1M,
```

Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

UPDATE: Seemed that the test board flash was corrupted. I tried with another one and the code worked fine.

Comment: What version of IDF are you using? Are the boards you used both of the same type? In particular, what flash chip/ID are they using? Is that the same? Today I saw a very similar issue which has probably been caused by a bug in the flash code of IDF. If you need help finding the commands to answer the questions above, let me know, please.

Comment: I updated my question: the board that I was testing on, was corrupted, Tested with another one, and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this note in the documentation for [nvs_set_u8()](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/storage/nvs_flash.html#_CPPv410nvs_set_i812nvs_handle_tPKc6int8_t):

> Note that actual storage will not be updated until nvs_commit function is called.

So add a call to `nvs_commit()` immediately after `nvs_set_u8()`:

```
ret = nvs_commit(handler);
log_e("nvs_commit CODE: %d", ret);
```

Comment: Hi, I realized that and edited my question. With nvs_commit() I have the same result. Thank you!

Comment: @SXN Perhaps it would be better to commit right after the write (set) operation. If you commit after the read (get) operation it has no effect on the read. What I did not understand was, you perform the commit after the get in the code, but it was logged before the get ???? Hhhm strange!

Comment: Let me repeat myself: "add a call to nvs_commit() *immediately after* nvs_set_u8()" ;)

Comment: Yes, I re-edited my question. I added nvs_commit right after nvs_set_i8 but still same error code. I even modified my partition table,added a new custom NVS partition with custom name and same result. I searched on all threads and forums but I cannot find a solution or an explanation. That makes it harder.

Comment: Ah, OK. I've seen the NVS code get confused if you change the partition scheme and re-run the app. What you can try next is erasing all flash with `idf.py erase_flash`, then re-flashing and re-running your app.

Comment: Already did that, both from CLI and code: same result. Seems that it does not find the key, which is strange. Maybe this particular board with 16MB flash is faulty, tough I doubt it.